# Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.9.5 requires a newer version of Windows to display Content, but newer windows is banned

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

when i want to see design of

```
Mainpage.xaml
```

autocreated by VS **Windows Universal Blank App** it shows me that i need newer Windows (pic)

[image]

then, when i try to update, Windows Update Manager cant find newer version of System. It is caused by [re-released version of Windows from October 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history)
Have you any idea how to fix that? Any fixes fron internet like [this](https://appuals.com/windows-10-wont-install-or-download-updates/), and [this](https://www.alphr.com/microsoft/1001411/how-to-fix-windows-update-in-windows-10-if-it-becomes-stuck-1), didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478053/visual-studio-requires-a-newer-version-of-windows-to-display-this-content?rq=1).

What You have to do is:

1. From menu bar select **Project**
2. **YOUR_PROJECT Properties**
3. Change **Target version** to **Windows 10(10.0)**

[image: wtd]